# Update join table HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a relationship between two models:

House and Person

```
class House
   has_and_belongs_to_many :persons
end
```

I have a join table like this:

```
house_id | person_id | used
1          1           false
```

I need to update used to "true" using this code:

```
h = house.persons.find(params[:person_id])
h.update_attribute(:used, true) # ERROR used column doesn't exists in persons table
```

How can I update the column used in join table ?
Thanks.

Comment: You need to use HABTM though: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many

Comment: Don't use HABTM if you want to store extra data on the join table. Use `has_many though:`.  HABTM is extremely limitied and only allows you to create / query the join table indirectly.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use the has_many and belongs_to relationships between your three tables: persons, houses and the join_table explicitly in code layer.

```
class House
   has_many :persons, through: :person_houses
   has_many :person_houses
end

class Person
   has_many :houses, through: :person_houses
   has_many :person_houses
end

#join table
class PersonHouse
   belongs_to :person
   belongs_to :house
end
```

Then you can update the used attribute as given below:

```
person_house = house.person_houses.find_by(person_id: params[:person_id])
person_house.update(used: true)
```

**Edit**
you should never use HABTM, if you want to add attributes to your join table and interact with your join table (credit to max in the comments for explaining this)

Comment: I'm doing exactly your code but got this error: NoMethodError (undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  to_s):

Comment: you get this error when updating the instance of join table? What version of rails are you using?

Comment: rails version 5.1.4

Comment: my join table doesn't have ID column, could be this ?

Comment: Can you post what person_house contains exactly? also what house.person_houses is returning and params[:person_id]

Comment: Just added an id column to my table and worked. Because on update query the join table doesn't have an id. The problem is that I can't add an id to this join table.

Comment: how did you create the join table? id gets added to the join table automatically when you create it using rails migration. Also, this field is auto increment and it should get inserted to the table automatically, every time you insert a new record in your table.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the same except instead of `PersonHouse`, create an actual model called `Lease` or `Deed` with the attribute `used`. This should make your code alot cleaner.