# rails HABTM to model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 models user and category. each user will select multiple categories of data, I'm using HABTM. Is this right method?. If yes How can I store multiple category details with each user in join table?

Comment: Question is too broad, if you split the question into multiple questions .. I am pretty sure that you would find the answers you are looking for already answered here in SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use HABTM, if you want to add attributes to your join table and interact with your join table.

Use has_many though. You can read more about it in the docs below

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many

Comment: Ok If I use has_many through, how to save the join table data? Is it like User.save or Category.save?

Comment: In that case, you will have three tables: `User`, `Category` and `UserCategory`. you will save the join table using `user_category.save`. Please make sure you create your join table in a separate migration. Also, look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47460064/update-join-table-habtm/47460832#47460832

Comment: I'm using has many through, Now how to save data for join table with function getting data from api? EX: {{"user_id":1,"category_id":1},{"user_id":1,"category_id":2}}

Comment: Why are you using **has_many through** if there are only two columns user_id and category_id? HABTM should suffice. As for saving the data in join table. You can do the following.
`User.find(1).categories = Category.where(id: [1,2])`

Comment: he wants to save multiple category details in the join table. please read the question again